# Any way to snapshot a series of steps within an answer, churn of comments is making it hard to follow what I should be trying as the OP?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

I am currently trying to go through a series of steps that one of the community members posted in their answer. But since all the other members are commenting, I'm finding it difficult to keep the conversation focused on a particular version of these steps. A snapshot of the steps would give an exact meaning to the post.

What can be done about this?

Comment: What is an assured meaning? What workout are you referring to. Members of what organisation (or do you mean U&L users (<-that is the terminology we use here see the menu bar directly below the sites title ))?

Comment: I have no idea what you're even talking about.

Comment: @Anthon yes i am talking about U&L members.

Comment: Are you talking about this post? http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171214/33055 What is the problem with that?

Comment: What is this workout that you're talking about?

Comment: @slm I did it here. [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171214/append-time-to-log-filenames)

Comment: The term workout is being used incorrectly. It doesn't mean what you're describing.

Comment: I agree. thanks for clarifications! @slm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're talking about the dynamic nature of the content on the site (questions & answers) in combination with the commenting that can occur. It takes a little getting used to but there isn't really anything you can do beyond looking through the edit history on either your question or on the various answers you receive when asking questions.

**NOTE:** Each question and answer has a edit link under it where you can see a full history of the various changes that were made over time and by whom.

With time you'll adapt to the pace at which solutions to your question are thrown at you, and can evolve over time.

Stack Exchange sites are unique in this dynamic nature, most people are accustom to a more traditional forum where you ask your question and then it remains there in stasis, and you as the questioner don't have to do a lot of interacting afterwords.

Here questions and answers can be edited as new information is revealed, so it's expected that questioners take a more active role in helping to solve their questions.